# is there Og meta tags for WhatsApp?

Tags: html, meta

My website thumbnail is not showing on WhatsApp meanwhile on Facebook its totally fine i already added the OG meta tags this is my code please help

```
 <head>
      <meta property="og:url"content="http://www.mywebsite.com"/>
      <meta property="og:type"content="article"/>
      <meta property="og:title"content="text text text !!"/>
      <meta property="og:description"content="text about my webiste."/>
      <meta property="og:image"content="http://www.website.com/images/logo.png"/>
      <meta property="og:image:width" content="600"/>
      <meta property="og:image:height" content="314"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was primarily with the image size, as the image that was not displayed was 1920 by 1080, and Whatsapp apparently does not process images that large for og:image. i resized it to 600 by 600 and it worked perfectly.